# Force fetching a file from git remote

Tags: git, azure-devops

There are many similar questions to this one, but I have not found a solution among them.

Our Azure DevOps remote holds a Visual Studio solution file that I would like to edit, but my local copy does not have it. The usual commands for fetching a file are unsuccessful:

- Verified connection to remote (able to pull other changes)
- Verified branch name (it's correct)
- Compared last commit hash (the same)
- `git pull`
- `git fetch`
- `git checkout .` from root
- `git checkout <path-to-file>`
- `git reset origin/<branch-name> --hard`
- Checked `.gitignore` (no gitignore file)
- Checked `git config --global core.excludesfile` (empty)
- Verified upstream branch is correct with `git remote -v`
- `git submodule update --checkout --recursive -f` (no change)

`git status` states the working tree is clean and I am up to date with the correct origin branch. I can remedy this problem by completely wiping the repository and starting over, but it continues to recur so I am interesting in finding the solution and cause.

Comment: Are you using sparse checkout (e.g., `git sparse-checkout list`)?  Have you set any of the assume-unchanged or skip-worktree bits with `git update-index` or any other approach?

Comment: It seems like you’ve already tried several troubleshooting steps. In this scenario, please double confirm the file is in the DevOps repo, and try to clone the repository again. This will create a fresh copy of the repository on your local machine. If cloning the repository again doesn’t work, try creating a new branch and checking out the file from the new branch for a check. In addition, please try on the clone on a new machine.

Comment: Good ideas -- A re-clone fixed the issue, so I will have to wait until the issue crops up again to keep experimenting. I've confirmed it is not a sparse repo and neither special bit is set, at least on a fresh copy.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you! I have posted the answer below, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't marked the solution as it doesn't address the cause. I'm more interested in preventing it from recurring than fixing this specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’ve already tried several troubleshooting steps, please try to clone the repository again.

This will create a fresh copy of the repository on your local machine. If cloning the repository again doesn’t work, try creating a new branch and checking out the file from the new branch for a check. Also please check clone on a new machine.